# resize image or video in ioslides

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

How do I resize an image or embedded video in ioslides? What works for a simple .html output (adjusting width and height as below) does not seem work when generating slies with ioslides_presentation:

```
---
title: "test"
author: ""
date: "January 12, 2016"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## test video 

<div align="center">
<iframe width="400" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_LGkbvkCS3I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: you should give a try to this package https://github.com/ijlyttle/vembedr by Ian Lytte. Easy and efficient